# Is it possible to fetch a link table without fetching all links?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Ok, so first of I would like to say that I'm using NHibernate for my project, and in this project we have (among other things) a sync function (to sync from a central MSSQL database to a local SQLite). Now I know that NHibernate was not made to sync databases, but I would like to do this anyways.

I have a medium large database model so I can't add it here, but the problem is that I have two datatables, and one link table to link them both.

Database model:

```
| Product            | | ProductLinkProducer | | Producer            |
|--------------------| |---------------------| |---------------------|
| Id                 | | LinkId              | | Id                  |
| Name               | | Product             | | Name                |
| ProductLinkProducer| | Producer            | | ProductLinkProducer |
```

Database:

```
| Product | | ProductLinkProducer | | Producer |
|---------| |---------------------| |----------|
| Id      | | LinkId              | | Id       |
| Name    | | ProductId           | | Name     |
|         | | ProducerId          | |          |
```

So during the sync, I first copy all data from the Product table, and then from the Producer table (basically `var products = session.Query<Products>().ToList()`). This is done by NHibernate in a single statement each:

```
select
    product0_.id as id2_,
    product0_.name as name2_
from
    Product product0_
```

Now I have to evict all items from the first session (`products.ForEach(x => session.Evict(x));`)

And then the save (`products.ForEach(x => syncSession.save(x));`) is one insert per row (as expected).

So when saving the data in the link table I would have wished that there also would be just a single *select*. However that is not the case. Because first it makes a `select ...` as above. But now before every row to *insert* it does even more *select* for the Product and for the Producer.

So it will look something like:

Products:

- select
- insert (id 1)
- insert (id 2)

Producer:

- select
- insert (id 101)
- insert (id 102)

ProdLinkProducer:

- select
- select id 1 from Products
- select id 1 from Products
- select id 101 from Producer
- select id 2 from Products
- select id 2 from Products
- select id 102 from Producer
- select id 102 from Producer
- insert
- insert

So is there anyway avoiding this behavior?

**EDIT**

To better explain what I have done, I have created a small test project. It can be found here: https://github.com/tb2johm/NHibernateSync
(I would have preferred to add only a ghist, but I think that it might have left out to much data, sorry...)

**EDIT2**

I have found out one way to make it work, but I don't like it.
The way this solution works is to in the database model create a ProductLinkProducerSync table, that doesn't contain any links, but just the values, and avoid synchronizing the ordinary link tables, but just the "sync" tables. But as I said I don't like this idea, since if I change anything in the database, I have kind of the same data in two places that I need to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find NHibernate out of the box way of doing what you are asking.

However I was able to get the desired behavior (I guess something is better than nothing:) by manually rebinding the FK references (proxy classes) to the new session:

```
var links = session.Query<ProductLinkProducer>().ToList(); 
links.ForEach(x => session.Evict(x));
foreach (var link in links)
{
    link.Product = syncSession.Get<Product>(link.Product.Id);
    link.Producer = syncSession.Get<Producer>(link.Producer.Id);
    syncSession.Save(link);
}
syncSession.Flush();
```

Here is the generalized version using NHibernate metadata services:

```
static IEnumerable<Action<ISession, T>> GetRefBindActions<T>(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    var classMeta = sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(typeof(T));
    var propertyNames = classMeta.PropertyNames;
    var propertyTypes = classMeta.PropertyTypes;
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyTypes.Length; i++)
    {
        var propertyType = propertyTypes[i];
        if (propertyType.IsAssociationType && !propertyType.IsCollectionType)
        {
            var propertyName = propertyNames[i];
            var propertyClass = propertyType.ReturnedClass;
            var propertyClassMeta = sessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(propertyClass);
            yield return (session, target) =>
            {
                var oldValue = classMeta.GetPropertyValue(target, propertyName, EntityMode.Poco);
                var id = propertyClassMeta.GetIdentifier(oldValue, EntityMode.Poco);
                var newValue = session.Get(propertyClass, id);
                classMeta.SetPropertyValue(target, propertyName, newValue, EntityMode.Poco);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and applying it to your `Sync` method:

```
private static void Sync<T>(string tableName, ISession session, ISession syncSession)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fetching data for ####{0}####...", tableName);
    var sqlLinks = session.Query<T>();
    var links = sqlLinks.ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("...Done");

    Console.WriteLine("Evicting data...");
    links.ForEach(x => session.Evict(x));
    Console.WriteLine("...Done");

    Console.WriteLine("Saving data...");
    var bindRefs = GetRefBindActions<T>(syncSession.SessionFactory).ToList();
    foreach (var link in links)
    {
        foreach (var action in bindRefs) action(syncSession, link);
        syncSession.Save(link);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("...Flushing data...");
    syncSession.Flush();
    Console.WriteLine("...Done");
    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
}
```